# Move handle of two related highstock charts at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I have a requirement where I have to move the handles of two highstock chart same time. So that if handle of any one of them is moved , then the handle for second chart gets re positioned accordingly.

JS fiddle is set up here [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/t8vwm1dm/)

Relevant code is something like

```
//callback function to set event              
   function(chart){
     Highcharts.addEvent(chart.xAxis[0], 'setExtremes', function (e) {
    var allRelatedChartsDiv = $("[data-identifier = '"+identifier+"']").not(chart); 
     $.each(allRelatedChartsDiv ,function(index,graphContainer){
        var chartObj = $(graphContainer).highcharts();  
        chartObj.xAxis[0].setExtremes(parseFloat(e.min),parseFloat(e.max));
  });
    });             
    });
```

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop / adapt this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/33/ which allows to synchronise charts by using `setExtremes()`